# Create a warning prompt box that appears before parameters are set in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a Crystal Report for some of my users with a date range parameter set.  The volume of information that the SQL command returns means that anything over a 7 day period in the date parameter slows the report to unusable speeds and subsequently locks the DB for all other users.

Does anyone know of a way to create a prompt in Crystal Reports that will appear before the parameter set?  I.e. As soon as they select the report and click "Open", the first thing they see is a box saying "Please ensure a maximum 7 day date period".  Then upon clicking "OK" or something of my choosing, they are presented with the parameter fields and can continue with the report.

If this cannot be done, is there a way to restrict the parameters so that when the users select the start date, they can only select a maximum of 7 days after.

The other option, if it is doable, is to have them select the start date and then it auto complete the end date with a date 7 days after the start date.

At the moment i have just added (Must be a 7 day period) to the parameter title but i dont feel this does a good enough job at advertising it and as soon as i publish it i know someone will want to get 4/5 years worth of data...our clinicians will be most unimpressed if they PAS system locks up during a busy clinic.

I have attached a screenshot of the kind of thing i am after.  It is a little crude as it was done in paint but it gets the point across.

I have searched high and low for this solution so i am not sure it even exists, but am asking out of sheer desperation.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Crystal Report solely (not within a program like .Net app) you can select your latest proposition. Get start date and in your SQL command (View, Stored Procedure, ...) select items from startDate to startDate + 7 days.

Depending on your DBMS there are ways to add some value to date (like dateadd function in MSSQL).

So its done.

Comment: Good thinkin'!  For some reason it hadnt occurred to me to do the work in the SQL code!  The solution i have used is "where HDATE between {?edate} and DATE_ADD({?edate}, INTERVAL 7 DAY)".  Obviously "{?edate}" is the start date parameter!  Thanks for your help!